# Travering through specific Azure Blob Storage directory and deleting all files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**The goal:** Delete all files within a specific directory, including files within nested folders.

**The problem:** Deleting the directory itself does not work as this returns an error:

> Exception: The specified blob does not exist

My Azure blob storage structure could look like this:

```
AzureFileStorageAccount
  AzureContainerName
    /themes
      /irrelevantstuff
    /images
      /a
        1.jpg
      /b
        /thumb
          1thumb.png
      /c
        4.jpg
      6.jpg
      9.jpg
      10.jpg
```

I don't know what any of the folder names are, but for the end result, I want to get a stack/list of all of the *actual files* found within a given directory.

For example, taking the `images` directory:

```
/images/a/1.jpg
/images/b/thumb/1thumb.png
/images/c/4.jpg
/images/6.jpg
/images/9.jpg
/images/10.jpg
```

To then, delete all of them.

---

Here's my *attempted* solution..

**LoadInitialDirectory** function:

```
public static void LoadInitialDirectory() {
    string initialDirectory = "images";

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureFileStorageAccount);
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(azureContainerName);
    CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(initialDirectory);

    var blobs = await directory.ListBlobSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 350, null, null, null);
    foreach(var blob in blobs.Results)
    {
        var b = new CloudBlob(blob.Uri);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(b.Name);
        if (blockBlob.Exists()) {
            // I will assume this is a file
            ProcessFile(blockBlob.Uri);
        }
        else {
            // This is another directory
            ProcessDirectory(blockBlob.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**ProcessDirectory** function:

```
public static void ProcessDirectory(string innerDirectory) {
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureFileStorageAccount);
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(azureContainerName);
    CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(innerDirectory);

    var blobs = await directory.ListBlobSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 350, null, null, null);
    foreach(var blob in blobs.Results)
    {
        var b = new CloudBlob(blob.Uri);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(b.Name);
        if (blockBlob.Exists()) {
            ProcessFile(blockBlob.Uri);
        }
        else {
            ProcessDirectory(blockBlob.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**ProcessFile** function:

```
public static void ProcessFile(string innerDirectory) {
    myStack.push(innerDirectory);
}
```

At the end of this, I should have a stack of blob Uri strings that I can iterate through and delete by the `DeleteAsync` method, therefore deleting the initial directory.

This seems to be overkill. Does anyone have any ideas for more compact, straightforward solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one thing you should note: in blob storage, the directory(and sub-directory) is actually treated as part of the blob name. If you delete all the blobs inside a directory, the directory will be deleted automatically.

The way to delete all the blobs inside a directory(and it's sub-directories) is that list all the blobs, then delete the blob one by one.

Assume you're using this blob storage package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, version 11.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/), then you can use `blobDirectory.ListBlobs()` method and set the parameter `useFlatBlobListing as true` which let you iterate through all the blobs within a specified directory(and as well as within the sub-directories).

The sample code is as below, and works for me:

```
        var conn_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        var myContainer = "aaa";
        var myDirectory = "images";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn_str);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(myContainer);
        CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(myDirectory);

        //set useFlatBlobListing as true, so you can list all the blobs in the directory(and it's sub-directories)
        var blobs = blobDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);

        //iterate through all the blobs in the specified directory(and it's sub-directories)
        foreach (var myblob in blobs)
        {
            var b = (CloudBlockBlob)myblob;

            //print out some properties of the blob, just for testing purpose.
            Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(b.Uri);
            Console.WriteLine("***********");

            //delete the blob
            b.Delete();
        }
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I had no need for any recursion. `useFlatBlobListing` was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be done from a console, I'd highly recommend using azure CLI and `az storage blob delete-batch` command.

See this for more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch